# Converting st_make_grid object to shapefile using R

Tags: r, polygon, convert, vector-grid

I've created the following grid:

```
my_grid_geom = st_make_grid(CLC18, cellsize = 0.4)
my_grid = st_sf(geom = my_grid_geom)
plot(my_grid)
```

I would like to convert this grid now into a shapefile for further processing in ArcMap.

How would I proceed with the conversion of such a polygon object?

Answer (score 1):

Herewith the solution to converting an st_make_grid into a shapefile:

```
my_grid_geom = st_make_grid(CLC18, cellsize = 0.4)
my_grid = st_sf(geom = my_grid_geom)
plot(my_grid)
st_write(my_grid,"my_grid.shp")
```